# How to use authentication details with a QNetWorkRequest in bb cascades?

Tags: blackberry-10, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I want to create a BB10 application using bb cascades in which i want to pass username and password to the server with a QNetWork http request. I tried the following

```
QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest();
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Language", "en-US");

QString concatenated = "username:password";
QByteArray data = concatenated.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
QString headerData = "Basic " + data;
req.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());

QSslConfiguration config = request.sslConfiguration();
config.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1);
request.setSslConfiguration(config);
```

But this gives me an QNetworkReply error 202(`ContentOperationNotPermittedError`).What is the reason for this error? How can i solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have an update on this ?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me

```
QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest();
request.setRawHeader("Authorization","Basic " +   QByteArray(QString("%1:%2").arg(USER_NAME).arg(PASSWORD).toAscii()).toBase64());
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Language", "en-US");
QSslConfiguration config = request.sslConfiguration();
config.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1);
request.setSslConfiguration(config);
```